# how to make sublime treat . handlebars that same as it would a .html file

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, sublimetext3

Just getting into using handlebars, and pretty new at sublime.  Since all my handlebar code is in a .handlebar, sublime treat it like it would a normal .html file (with autocomplete and pretty colors).  How can I change this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with `View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extensions as... -> HTML` while viewing a file saved as `.handlebars`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the bottom right of your sublime window, there should be a little box that says 'text'. Click on it and select HTML in the window that pops up. You are now writing HTML with a .handlebars extension!

Answer (score 0):

Not a spectacular solution as it will probably override any fancy handlebars packages you have installed, but you can tell Sublime that you want to open all `handlebars` files as HTML files `View > Syntax > Open all with current extension as > HTML`.